# How to tell Netbeans 7.3 NOT to build a war file

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.3

I read a lot how to build a war file. 
But is there a way to tell Netbeans to skip this step while builing the project?

I don´t know for sure. But hasn´t there been a checkbox "build war file" in an older Version of Netbeans?

Comment: please have a look at this: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56424

Comment: Ups! The solution is 8 years old... 2005-03-15 13:54:09 UTC

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. my boss came by :)